# Maven to Gradle migration - Assembly Plugin `includeBaseDirectory` equivalent

Tags: maven, gradle

I'm migrating a project from Maven to Gradle and having trouble replicating the tarball that the Maven Assembly Plugin creates. In Assembly XML file I use `<includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>` to create an archive without the project root. So...

```
/projectAbc/bin/start.sh
/projectAbc/lib/app.jar
/projectAbc/conf/dev/app.conf
```

... becomes...

```
/bin/start.sh
/lib/app.jar
/conf/dev/app.conf
```

... inside the tarball.

How do I achieve the same result in Gradle?

I'm using Gradle Distribution Plugin `distTar` task to build the archive.

Comment: May I ask why you want to move to Gradle?

Comment: @JFMeier A few reasons: Gradle seems to generally more flexible; I'm working with Kotlin and enjoying the Kotlin DSL and IDE support when working in the build file; lately Gradle seems to perform better than Maven (didn't used to IMHO); more options / flexibility on how to do releases (from my recent limited observations).